# HTML text from one ViewController to another's Webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

the purpose: write some html code in viewcontroller1's text field press button, the result is shown in webview in viewcontroller2
This is what i've written so far

```
#import <UIKit/UIkit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface vc1 : UIViewController

        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton * btn;
        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField * tf;
```

the text field can be just a standard one, all i need to do is make sure 
that when the user hits the button the vc2 comes up and in it's HTML section 
is a string that i got from the textfield
the method responsible for this action is mentioned below

```
 -(IBAction) btnAction : (id) sender;

    @end

    @interface vc2 : UIViewController

        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView * wv;

    @end
```

//didn't find standard implementation for vc1
//attempted implementation for vc1

```
@implementation vc1
@synthesize btn, tf;
-(id) initWithNibName: (NSString *)nibName0rNil bundle: (NSBundle *)nibBundle0rNil{
    self = [super initWithNibName: nibName0rNil bundle: nibBundle0rNil];
    if(self){
        //custom init
    }
    return self;
}

-(IBAction) btnAction : (id) sender {
    //initialize vc2? it's a class so i can't call it.
    //can i save the contents of the object as a NSString? or can i just give the Webview a textfield object to show as HTML?


 }

@end

@implementation vc2
@synthesize wv;

-(id) initWithNibName: (NSString *)nibName0rNil bundle: (NSBundle *)nibBundle0rNil{
    self = [super initWithNibName: nibName0rNil bundle: nibBundle0rNil];
    if(self){
        //custom init
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
```

this is where i am supposed to tell it to take the text from vc1 and display it as HTML

```
[wv loadHTMLString:@"<html><body>YOUR-TEXT-HERE</body></html>" baseURL:nil]
```

something of the sort but the string is replaced with what was inserted into vc1's text field
    }

```
-(void)viewDidUnload{
    [self setWebview: nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToTinterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaveOrientation{
    return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

@end
```

Edit: thank you for posting, this community has been very helpful.

Comment: How do you go from VC1 to VC2 ? There are plenty of tutorial about passing var from a VC to another VC. What have you tried/read?

Comment: i was forced to jump into objective-c for an assignment....i've studied this language for about 36 hours now. i will look into that right now. and post updates, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Interface of `vc2.h` declare a property like

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *htmlString;
```

In `vc1.h` file  or `vc1.h` add

```
#import "vc2.h"
```

Now in the Button Action Use the following code:

```
-(IBAction) btnAction : (id) sender {
    //initialize vc2? it's a class so i can't call it.
    //can i save the contents of the object as a NSString? or can i just give the Webview a textfield object to show as HTML?
   //With Xib 
     vc2 *secondVC =[[vc2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"vc2" bundle:nil];
     secondVC.htmlString = self.tf.text;//textField property name
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
 }
```

Finally to display the WebView in `vc1.m` use :

```
NSString *myHTMLString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", self.htmlString];
[self.wv loadHTMLString:myHTMLString baseURL:nil];
```

Hope this helps. Please let me know in case of any specific errors.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController

secondViewController.myStringValue = myTextField.text
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

Load the webview in the secondViewController's viewDidload method